# displaying error products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, redux

[this is my component file and when I run this code displaying error products.map is not a function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dehc7.png)

Answer (score 1):

this means products is not an array , try console logging the products and see what it's returning .
else you can make it map through only if the products exist like this

```
products?.map
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.map` function is only available on array.
It looks like `products` isn't in the format you are expecting it to be `(it is {} but you are expecting [])`